# Warning 'myframe-Bridging-Header.h' in Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I updated Xcode to Version 8.3 (8E162) and in my unit test file I have this warning:

> Implicit import of bridging header 'myframe-Bridging-Header.h' via
>   module 'myframe' is deprecated and will be removed in a later version
>   of Swift

on this line:

```
@testable import myframe
```

How to fix this warning?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That article helped me to fix the warning: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3801

I selected:

> chain the import by adding #import "App-Bridging-Header.h" to any
>   existing unit test bridging header you have

Answer (score 8):

So it has nothing to do with that line per se (which threw me for a loop) and you are not supposed to change it. What is happening is that the `@testable import` would normally automatically import the module bridging header as well and now it does not anymore.

Like [SR-3801](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3801) says the solution is to either:

> 1. explicitly import the App bridging header into your unit tests (via a build setting) or
> 2. chain the import by adding #import "App-Bridging-Header.h" to any existing unit test bridging header you have

I already had a `Test-Bridging-Header.h` where I added `#import "MODULE-Bridging-Header.h"` as part of solution 2 which I think is preferable. Now the test bridging header chains in the module bridging header and the warning disappears.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a different case (framework and no unit-test) :

I had a project combining Swift and ObjC (Meaning I already had a bridge-header). Project embeded a 3rd party framework. The warning yielded as the framework was added (shouting on their's bridge header). I just imported their header **inside my existing bridge-header**:

`#import <ThirdPartyFramework/ThirdPartyFramework-Bridging-Header.h>`

And warning suppressed.

Xcode 9.4.1
Swift 4.1